# Nested "with()" laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having issues with some relationships. I have the following situation

Product:

```
public function catalogues()

 {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Catalogue');
 }

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Category:

```
 public function products()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
   }
```

Catalogue:

```
    public function products()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
   }
```

With a single query, I need to get all the categories that have products belonging to a certain catalogue. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You need [join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `whereHas()`:

```
Category::whereHas('products.catalogues', function($q) use($catalogueId) {
    $q->where('catalogues.id', $catalogueId);
})
->get();
```

Or:

```
Category::whereHas('products', function($q) use($catalogueId) {
    $q->whereHas('catalogues', function($q) use($catalogueId) {
        $q->where('id', $catalogueId);
    })
})
->get();
```

Comment: This won't work either, it retrieves all the products from those categories.

Comment: @Dani it can't retrieve any products, it will return categories only. Do not modify the code, use it as is.

Comment: Thanks. In Laravel Backpack, I was able to use `$this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->whereHas('contactTags', function($q) use($tagId) {
                $q->where('tag_id', $tagId);
            });`

Answer (score 0):

You need `whereHas` and

```
    Category::whereHas('products')
  ->with(['products' => function($query) use ($id){
        $query->with('catalogues' => function($query) use ($id){

         $query->where('catalogues.id',$id);

      });

   }])
  ->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but actually what I need to do later is to loop it by category, not by products. That's why I'm a little confused, as I tried the "with" method, which works perfectly if I just pick the products, not if I join the catalogues too as there's no relationship b/w catalogues and categories

Comment: @Dani I have updated the answer have a look. it may helps you

Comment: Amazing, this works! Thank you, you saved me from a huge headache :)

Comment: @Dani I am glad this works for you. If this really worked for you can accept this answer.

Comment: @Dani this can't possibly work for you because this code will give you an error and `with()` will load the data instead of filtering categories by related data.

Comment: You are right, I was testing on a catalogue that had all the products.